# Trying to avoid redirect loop in custom php geolocation script

Tags: php, redirect, infinite-loop

I have created a script for determining the country of a user to give them content specific to the country (e.g. currencies, etc,.).

This script is included in the header of all pages on the site because I want them to be able to change country if they want to (e.g. they might be abroad but still want content from home).

If it finds the posted variable it will change the country and redirect back to the home page. This will cause a redirect loop however, as the script is also included on this and other pages which then looks for the posted variable again but can't find it.

I am not giving custom content for all countries just specific countries I have saved in a database.

My script is as follows

```
<?php
$ip;
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$content = file_get_contents('https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host='.$ip);
$jsonArray = json_decode($content, true);
$country = "";
foreach($jsonArray['data']['geo'] as $key => $value){
    if($key != 'country_name'){
    }else{
        $country = $value;
    }
}

$active_country_id;
$active_country_name = "";
$active_country_code;
$active_country_currency;

$country_active = "";
$country_menu = "";

if(!isset($_GET["country_id"])){
    $sql1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country='$country'");
    $countryCount1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
    if ($countryCount1 > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){ 
            $active_country_id = $row["id"];
            $active_country_name = $row["country"];
            $active_country_code = $row["code"];
            $active_country_currency = $row["currency"];

            $country_active .= "$active_country_code";
            $country_active .= " - ";
            $country_active .= "$active_country_name";
        }
    } else {
        $country_active = "No Countries";
    }
}else{
    $new_country_id = $_GET["country_id"];
    $sql1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id='$new_country_id'");
    $countryCount1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
    if ($countryCount1 > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){ 
            $active_country_id = $row["id"];
            $active_country_name = $row["country"];
            $active_country_code = $row["code"];
            $active_country_currency = $row["currency"];

            $country_active .= "$active_country_code";
            $country_active .= " - ";
            $country_active .= "$active_country_name";
        }
    } else {
        $country_active = "No Countries";
    }
    //header("location: index.php"); 
}

$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country!='$active_country_name'");
$countryCount2 = mysqli_num_rows($sql2);
if ($countryCount2 > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){ 
        $country_id = $row["id"];
        $country_name = $row["country"];
        $country_code = $row["code"];
        $country_currency = $row["currency"];

        $country_menu .= "<li><a href='country.php?country_id=$country_id'>";
        $country_menu .= "$country_code";
        $country_menu .= " - ";
        $country_menu .= "$country_name";
        $country_menu .= "</a></li>";
    }
} else {
    $country_menu = "No other Countries";
}
?>
```

I want to perform the redirect on the commented out line `//header("location: index.php");`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a huge SQL injection gap here – you need to escape what you get from your `$_GET` before handing it to MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve put your redirection in the `else` where `country_id` exists as a request. You should look for where `country_id` is missing, then redirect with `country_id`.

It will be easier to read your own code if you refactor it into

```
if (true) {
    // stuff
} else {
    // other stuff
}
```

If you use `if (!$something)` followed by an `else`, the else becomes a double negative (not not) and it’s confusing to read. Try using `if ($_GET...)` first, then an `else`.

Or... you could also just not have an `else` and design your script around only doing a redirect when required, otherwise letting it carry on.

```
if (!$_GET['country_id']) {
    // redirect with country_id
}
// Carry on with page as normal
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about  the double negative, that was from trying a few other things out before I posted here and just didn't change it back... the issue is that when the condition is true it redirects to another page that  includes this script again but will not meet the same conditions again... was thinking I will need to set a session or cookie variable that is persistent so that the same conditions are met otherwise it hits the else condition and just resets what it should be

Comment: Your best bet is probably to set it as a cookie, otherwise you’ll end up having to include it on every link you make. Say you call your cookie `country_preference`, then you could just look for `if (!$_COOKIE["country_preference"])` and then run the script, which’ll set the cookie. Note this needs to happen before you print anything. If you need the user to override it, then allow for that get request to come first, and then if it’s not set, then allow the cookie through.